# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p(n)q(n)}{n^2}.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, solution-verification

> Question: Let $p(n)$ be the number of digits when $8^n$ is written in base $6$, and let $q(n)$ be the number of digits when $6^n$ is written in base $4$. Then evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p(n)q(n)}{n^2}.$$

Solution: Select any positive integer $n$ (written in base $10$) and any base $b$. Let $n=(a_ka_{k-1}\dots a_0)_b,$ that is $$n=a_k b^k+a_{k-1}b^{k-1}+\cdots+a_1b+a_0.$$ Now note that for all $0\le i\le k-1$, we have $0\le a_i\le b-1$ and $1\le a_k\le b-1$ (since $a_k\neq 0$). This implies that for all $0\le i\le k-1$, we have $0\le a_ib^i\le (b-1)b^i$ and $b^k\le a_kb^k\le (b-1)b^k$. Thus, we have $$b^k\le a_k b^k+a_{k-1}b^{k-1}+\cdots+a_1b+a_0\le (b-1)(b^k+b^{k-1}+\cdots+b+1)=b^{k+1}-1<b^{k+1},$$ that is, $$b^k\le n<b^{k+1}\implies k\le \log_b n<k+1.$$ This implies that for any positive integer $n$ (written in base $10$) and any base $b$, if $n$ has $k+1$ digits when written in base $b$, then we must have $$k\le \log_b n<k+1.$$ Therefore, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $$p(n)-1\le \log _6{8^n}<p(n)\\\implies p(n)-1\le 3n\log_6 2 <p(n)\\\implies 3n\log_6 2<p(n)\le 1+3n\log_6 2\hspace{0.2 cm}\dots (1).$$

Again, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $$q(n)-1\le \log _4{6^n}<q(n)\\\implies q(n)-1\le \frac{1}{2}n\log_2 6 <q(n)\\\implies \frac{1}{2}n\log_2 6<q(n)\le 1+\frac{1}{2}n\log_2 6\hspace{0.2 cm}\dots (2).$$  Multiplying (1) and (2) and dividing the resultant inequality by $n^2$, we have $$\frac{3}{2}<\frac{p(n)q(n)}{n^2}\le \left(\frac{1}{n}+3\log_6 2\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2}\log_2 6\right).$$ Now since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}+3\log_6 2\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2}\log_2 6\right)=\frac{3}{2},$$ therefore by Sandwich theorem we can conclude that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p(n)q(n)}{n^2}=\frac{3}{2}.$$

Is this solution correct and is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: I see no errors. But your references to $n$ being "written in base $10$" are rather quixotic, as you make no use at all of the base $10$ representation of $n$. Also pointing out that $\log_62$ and $\log_26$ are inverses would make your proof easier to follow. I didn't notice you'd put the two logarithms in symmetric form until I wondered at their disappearence in the product. I would also simplify the RH product and bring the $\frac 32$ term outside the limit to make that part of the argument more clear.

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2269250p17645107